# Identify Sci-fi book set in Australia

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to locate the title and author of a book I read, the plot is something like this:

- In the future / alternate reality.
- A young programmer works for a corporation and he hates it - longs for something else.
- He meets a girl who tells him she's secretly planning (with a secret club kind of thing) to leave her job for a trip to Australia (for some reason I can't remember).
- After chasing her around the city, the girl finally reveals how to join the secret club and go on the trip.
- He goes, but instead of a trip his plane crashes and he realizes that the trip is scam to weed out non-conformists and now he's stuck in the middle of Australian Outback, basically left to die.

The rest of the book is his journey across Australia and trying to survive... I won't give away the ending.

Can anyone help me remember the title & author of this book?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. It might help for identification purposes to give away the ending. You can hide the text by prepending the line with ">!". Users will have to mouse over the hidden text to see it.

Comment: Also, given your user name, are you sure it was Australia and not Austria?

Comment: Please don't intentionally withhold information. You're just making it harder for people to help you :-(

Comment: *The Matrix* was filmed in Australia.  Thomas Anderson is a young programmer who longs for something else.  He meets Trinity, who belongs to a secret club.  He goes on a trip down the rabbit hole with her.  His trip was kind of a "scam", because he wakes up hairless in a pool of liquified dead bodies...

Answer (score 8):

**Getting Back** by William Dietrich

https://www.librarything.com/work/564231/descriptions

Stifled and frustrated by company policy, Daniel jumps at the chance to go on a wilderness challenge in the Australian Outback. However, when he arrives he realises that the corporation does not intend for him to survive the trip.

It's the late 21st century and all's right with the world, which is exactly what's driving Daniel Dyson nuts. Unemployment, hunger, war, are all in the past since mass privatization has revolutionized the quality of life and the entire planet is now run by the ultra-efficient United Corporations, a single entity with a name that speaks for itself. Dyson loathes his drone-filled office in the Pacific Northwest, and the feeling is mutual. He resorts to small acts of sabotage for minor thrills until he encounters beautiful and dangerous Raven, who tells him about Outback Adventure--an updated Outward Bound.